# Destructuring assignment with JSON parsed string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I want to assign with the destructuring method a variable with a localStorage item.
This seems to work.

```
const { item } = localStorage
```

But my item is a stringified object and i want it as an object.

Is there way to make this work ?

```
const { JSON.parse(item) } = localStorage
```

Comment: `const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.item)`

Comment: ^ This. Don't overcomplicate it.

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would be less readable, wouldn't it?

Comment: Just trying  to use es6 syntax as mush as i can.

Comment: @AdrienCastagliola — ES6 syntax includes ES5 syntax.